# Compile C files with multiple main()

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compilation

I am a beginner in C and I have a question about compiling C files. I need to write a common package code (common.c) for an application with a main() to parse a config file and set few variables. I need to import this file in another file, say local.c using #include(?) and have a main() here again and call certain functions in common.c. Now when I compile these files using gcc, I am getting an error: multiple declaration for main().

Is there a way I can compile and run common.c first and use the variables set by this file in local.c? What makefile rules should I use?

common.h

```
#ifndef __DAEMON_COMMON__
#define __DAEMON_COMMON__

extern int a;
extern const char* type;
    
    
int add(int a, int b);
void print(int n);
    
#endif
```

common.c

```
int a = -1;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // parse file in arg and initialize variables declared as extern
    
    a = 10;
}
    
int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
    
void print(int n){
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

common.c and common.h are in common directory to be included in local.c using

```
#include <common.h>
```

local.c

```
#include <common.h>
    
int main(){
    add(5,10);
    print(a);  // I want to access 'a' initialized in common.c here
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Normally you include `.h` files, not `.c` files. Including `.c` files is wrong in most cases. (Of course, there are exceptions.) A `.h` file normally contains declarations of the functions and variables in the corresponding `.c` file to make them known for the code in other files. There must not be more than one `main` function. Please [edit] your question and tell why have two `main` functions. Show your code. If your source files are big, simplify them to create a [mre].

Comment: @Bodo One of the c files is in a different directory - common directory to be included in the local code. I have shared the code.

Comment: I think the different directory locations of your files affect only the required specification of include directories by using compiler options `-I some_include_dir`. If you have any problems with this fact, add details to your question about the location of all the example files and the current working directory from where you run the compiler.

Comment: Another question: Is the intended purpose of the `main` function in `common.c` the initialization of variables? Why don't you simply use `int a=10;` instead of `int a=-1`?

Comment: @Bodo This is a part of an embedded software project and common.c and common.h are a part of the system header files (include directory), so I will have #include<common.h> in local.c. The main() in common.c parses a files and initializes variables and in my local.c I have a main() where I call functions & use variables declared and defined in common.c & common.h

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all information from your comment to the question. If you have to write the code in `common.c` and `common.h` for your project, then it is not a system include file. (Anyway, using `#include <common.h>` will probably work. There might be tools that behave differently for `#include <...>` and `#include "..."`.) As already stated **you cannot have two functions with the same name.** If the concept from my answer doesn't solve your problem, please add details to your question to show why the solution does not work or cannot be used.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated in comments and as reported by the compiler, you cannot have more than one `main` function. You have to either exclude all but a single `main` function from the compilation or rename the other function(s) and call it (them) yourself.

The purpose of the `main` function in `common.c` seems to be the initialization of a variable. You can do this in different ways.

---

With the example from the question you can simply do the correct static initialization without using a function.

**common.h**

```
#ifndef __DAEMON_COMMON__
#define __DAEMON_COMMON__

extern int a;
extern const char* type;

int add(int a, int b);
void print(int n);

#endif
```

**common.c**

```
/* add this include here to allow the compiler to check your implementation against the declaration */
#include "common.h"

/* correct initialization here instead of a main() function */
int a = 10;

int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

void print(int n){
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

**local.c**

```
/* #include <...> is normally used for system include files, #include "..." for files from your project */
#include "common.h"
    
int main(){
    add(5,10); /* useless call because result is unused and no side effects in function */
    print(a);  // I want to access 'a' initialized in common.c here

    return 0;
}
```

---

Assuming that in your real use case the required initialization is more complicated and is intended to depend on command line arguments, this can be solved in different ways using an initialization function.

Note that the different options with conditional compilation using `OPTION1` or `OPTION3` in the code below are used to demonstrate different solutions in a single source code. Instead of implementing it this way you can simply choose the option that fits your requirements or that you like most.

**common.h**

```
#ifndef __DAEMON_COMMON__
#define __DAEMON_COMMON__

extern int a;
extern const char* type;

int add(int a, int b);
void print(int n);

/* option 1: main() processes command line args and calculates value */
void common_init_a(int value);

/* option 2: main() passes command line args for processing in common.c */
void common_init(int argc, char **argv);

#endif
```

**common.c**

```
#include "common.h"

int a = -1;

int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

void print(int n){
    printf("%d",n);
}

/* option 1 */
void common_init_a(int value) {
    a = value;
}

/* option 2 */
void common_init(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* process argc and argv to calculate the value for a */
    a = 10; /* In reality this is a calculated value, not a constant */
}
```

**local.c**

```
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    /* run the initialization of the common module */
#ifdef OPTION1
    /* option 1 */
    /* process argc and argv to calculate the value for a */
    common_init_a(10); /* In reality this is a calculated value, not a constant */
#else
    /* option 2 */
    common_init(argc, argv) {
#endif

    add(5,10);
    print(a);  // I want to access 'a' initialized in common.c here

    return 0;
}
```

The drawback of this solution is that the initialization must be explicitly called by any program that uses the `common` module.

---

You can improve this in several ways. You could save the "initialized" state in `common.c` and make your functions return an error in case it was not initialized before. If the initialization does not depend on input values, the functions could implicitly run the initialization if necessary.

**common.c**

```
#include "common.h"

/* option 3, see below */
static void init_internal(void);

int a = -1;

static int initialized = 0;

int add(int a, int b){
    if(!initialized) {
#ifndef OPTION3
        /* option 1 or 2 */
        /* handle error */
        return ERROR_INDICATION; /* not very useful for this "add" function, but maybe in the real use case */
#else
        /* option 3: implicit initialization as required */
        init_internal();
#endif   
    }
    return a + b;
}

void print(int n){
    printf("%d",n);
}

/* option 1 */
void common_init_a(int value) {
    a = value;
    initialized = 1;
}

/* option 2 */
void common_init(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* process argc and argv to calculate the value for a */
    a = 10; /* In reality this is a calculated value, not a constant */
    initialized = 1;
}

/* option 3: internal initialization without input values */
static void init_internal(void) {
    a = 10;
    initialized = 1;
}
```

**local.c**

```
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

/* With option 3, initialization is implicit in every function that requires it. */
#ifndef OPTION3

    /* run the initialization of the common_module */
# ifdef OPTION1
    /* option 1 */
    /* process argc and argv to calculate the value for a */
    common_init_a(10); /* In reality this is a calculated value, not a constant */
# else
    /* option 2 */
    common_init(argc, argv) {
# endif
#endif

    add(5,10);
    print(a);  // I want to access 'a' initialized in common.c here

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit** as a reply to a comment

> This is a part of an embedded software project [...]
> The `main()` in `common.c` parses a files and initializes variables and in my `local.c` I have a `main()` where I call functions & use variables declared and defined in `common.c` & `common.h`

You **must** rename one of the functions.

Instead of the solution shown above, where function `main()` from `local.c` calls a function `common_init()` or similar from `common.c` you could do it the other way round and require your specific (local) application code to have a function named `local_main()` (or any name of your choice defined by the function call in `common.c`) with a specific signature and behavior that will be called from `main()` in `common.c`.

Example:

common.h

```
#ifndef __DAEMON_COMMON__
#define __DAEMON_COMMON__

extern int a;
extern const char* type;
    
    
int add(int a, int b);
void print(int n);

/* declaration of required function in local.c */
int local_main(void);
    
#endif
```

common.c

```
#include "common.h"

int a = -1;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // parse file in arg and initialize variables declared as extern
    
    a = 10;

    return local_main();
}
    
int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
    
void print(int n){
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

local.c

```
#include "common.h"
    
int local_main(){
    add(5,10);
    print(a);  // I want to access 'a' initialized in common.c here
    
    return 0;
}
```